# How can set location of parent from pop up window opened by iframe.

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow

I want to set location of parent window from pop up window opened by iframe.

I am writing this line of code in javascript but it is not working.

```
window.opener.parent.location = '../Account/';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
window.opener.parent.location.href = '../account/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work with

```
window.parent.location.href = '../account/';
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this

```
<b>iframe starts here</b><br><br>
<iframe src='iframe1.html'></iframe>

<br><br>
<b>iframe ends here</b>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_parent_url(url)
    {
    document.location=url;
    }       
</script>
```

In iframe

```
<a href="javascript:parent.change_parent_url('http://yahoo.com');">
Click here to change parent URL </a>
```

So you can see that child iframe calls parent's function and gives **URL**